# How to refresh automatically a Power Query table of an Excel file saved in SharePoint?

Tags: powerquery, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I'm aware that this kind of question has been asked several times, but to be honest I haven't found yet a clear solution.

The thing is that I have an excel file located in Sharepoint which I would like to refresh its Power Query every morning. I'm just looking to a power automate flow that gets into the file, goes to "Data" tab and clicks "Refresh All" without the need of having my laptop on.

I've tried to use a simple flow in Power Automate Desktop using UI, but I wasn't able to connect it to a file out of my local folders. I've also created a flow that runs a script, but although it didn't provide any errors, the power query in the excel file never got updated. This is the code of the script:

`function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

```
// Refresh all data connections
workbook.refreshAllDataConnections();
workbook.refreshAllPivotTables();`
```

Is there any feasible solution to my issue? :)

Comment: I don’t believe it’s currently possible. That simple.